# how to quit os application with win32com in python

Tags: operating-system, win32com

```
import os
import win32com.client as win32

excel = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

os.startfile(r'C:\asdf.xlsx') ## open excel file

print(excel.Workbooks.Count) ## ==0

excel.Quit()  ## nothing happen
```

```
import os
import win32com.client as win32

excel = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

excel.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\asdf.xlsx') ## open excel file

print(excel.Workbooks.Count) ## ==1

excel.Quit()  ## is work
```

Comment: Use Task Manager to see how many instances of Excel you have running.

Comment: 2 instances of Excel running. one opened in window, the other in win32com.client

Comment: When an instance of Excel is started via COM, it seems that although the application appears in the Running Object Table, it is inaccessible to other processes. So when you use the shell to open a .xlsx file, the system starts a new, different Excel instance (rather than re-using the instance that is already running). So you are opening the file in a different instance. Well, that's what happens on my machine anyway.